# Is the ability to change armor color only available to preorders in XCOM: Enemy Unknown?

Tags: steam, xcom-enemy-unknown

Can armor color only be changed if you have a preordered version of XCOM?

On the customization screen I can change hair, face, name, etc, but I can't change the color of the armor.

UPDATE: Seems that the answer is yes, so the next question is this:
Is there anyway to get the Elite Soldier Pack DLC if you bought the game on Steam after release?

Comment: From what I hear it'll become available at some point in the near future -- possibly as a deluxe edition version. Can't access the steampowered forums from work or I'd give an actual answer with links to back it up.

Comment: I've seen references in the steam forum to being able to edit an ini file to enable the dlc, didnt save links unfortunately.

Comment: jeez, had I know it's worth something to ppl, I've wouldn't have redeemed the code, but rather sold it on eBay ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You won't get the special armor from the pre order, but you if you don't feel like buying the DLC, you can add the following lines to the end of your `XComGame.ini` in `C:\Users\<user>\Documents\My Games\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\Config`.

```
[XComStrategyGame.XGCustomizeUI]
bArmorDecoAvailable=true
bArmorTintAvailable=true
```

This will allow you to get the color customizations without the extra armor.

Comment: But without the Guile hair, the armour customization means nothing!

Comment: Yay, this worked, thanks! Although "Armor Deco" seems to always show "NOT AVAILABLE" for me, but at least colors can be customized now, which is very, very nice. In Steam version, the file seems to be `DefaultGame.ini` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\XCom-Enemy-Unknown\XComGame\Config`.

Answer (score 4):

The Elite Soldier pack is now available for separate purchase on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/209811/) and [Xbox LIVE](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Elite-Soldier-Pack/b945ddac-861c-4410-a6a3-d2f6833eae8c) (US marketplace link). I assume that if it's not already available on PSN, it will be soon as well.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. 
I'm in the same boat.

You could try and track down a preorder, seems to be a few on ebay for $100.
Or simply use a 'backup' copy if you catch my drift.

Other than that, we have to wait for the announcement that it's actually going to be released.

Comment: Bah, having to use a "backup copy" for a game I legally bought.

Answer (score 0):

If you buy the Special Edition of the game off of Amazon then you get the colors and stuff.